# Stop headers from adding a linebreak?

Tags: html, css, dom

I'm creating a small webstore, and the product name and price need to be on the same line. The product name and price are displayed as `h2`.

Is it possible to use two `h2` tags on the same line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`h1`, `h2` etc. are block elements, they get all width they can. You can use (see demo: http://jsfiddle.net/VZc4Q/):

```
h2 {
  display: inline;
}
```

But it is not good, I think, headers should be block elements. As a variant you can place name and price in spans and add style for it. Or place name and price in one header.

Comment: I tried placing name and price in one header, but as the name and/or price can change via javascript, I can't do that. I'll try that now.